# multiline and shifted equation number

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, multline, paper

code:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,superscriptaddress,
]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{multline}
    E= \\
    = \int 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
\end{multline}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

How to avoid this shifted equation number that appears when the equation is too long, without further dividing the equation?

[image]

Comment: why do you want to avoid it, it is by design. Where do you want the number?

Comment: aligned with the end of the first column

Comment: oh still under? in that case miss out the `\raisetag` in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

hide the overfull box with negative space, then raise the tag

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,superscriptaddress,
]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{multline}
    E= \\
    = \int 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
\hspace*{-20pt}
\raisetag{35pt}
\end{multline}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```